# Equirectangular projection and flattening horizon

Tags: rendering

I have been given some equirectangular projections from blender to visualize in VR. The rendering was done from within some 3d model. The horizon is almost like an S, so when I project it onto a sphere the perspective seems a bit off. Is there anything the blender guy can do to produce a flatter horizon, like restrict attitude of the sphere etc)?
[image]

Comment: Your description of your question is unclear. Could you perhaps provide screenshots?

Comment: sorry here is the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had too much experience with equirectangular rendering in Blender, but as a photographer I can say that this happens in real life when the camera is not level, so perhaps check that they have their camera rotations all set to 0. I was able to straighten it using a pitch of 30º and a rotation of -2º:

[image]

Comment: this looks better, seems reasonable because i think the guy just threw the camera in the model fairly arbitrarily

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you haven't UV unwrapped the sphere. [This tutorial explains the process well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U).

Comment: Okay thanks, I have no idea how he did this but I will point him in this direction